# Publish only one aar to maven central

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am struggling with following scenario.

I am developing an android library with two flavors paid + free. There are some differences in sources and resources that's why I must have two AARs. My business logic allows only to release the free version to MavenCentral. However `uploadArchives` takes all artifacts built by `assemble` task.

My current hack is to pass an argument `-Plib_version` to gradle:

```
if ("paid".equals(lib_version)) {
    defaultPublishConfig "paidRelease"
} else if ("free".equals(lib_version)) {
    defaultPublishConfig "freeRelease"
} else {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

So when I wanted to release only paid version my gradle run look like

```
./gradlew uploadArchives -Plib_version=free
```

Does anyone know a better trick? The best option would be to point MavenDeployer files to sign and upload.

Thanks